# Convert csv into tsv using pandas with escapechar

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a sample csv file contains

```
col1
"hello \n
world"
"the quick \njump
\n \r \t brown fox"
```

Sample code convert into tsv

```
import pandas as pd
df = read_csv(r'a.csv')

df.to_csv('data.tsv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', escapechar='\n')
```

Expecting result will be

```
col1
"hello \n world"
"the quick \njump \n \r \t brown fox"
```

But the result woud be

```
col1
"hello \n
world"
"the quick \njump
\n \r \t brown fox"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `escapechar` while reading the csv worked for me. But it skipping the double quotes when converting to tsv.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'a.csv', escapechar='\n')

df.to_csv('data.tsv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
col1
hello \nworld
the quick \njump\n \r \t brown fox
```